# "Balancing" a list of symbols

Tags: python, algorithm, list, python-3.x, numpy

Consider a list with elements drawn from a set of symbols, e.g. `{A, B, C}`:

```
List             --> A, A, B, B, A, A, A, A, A, B,  C,  C,  B, B
Indexing indices --> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
```

How I can re-order this list so that, for **any** symbol, we have approximately half of the symbols in the first half of the list i.e. `[0, [N/2]]` of the list and half on the second half? i.e. `[[N/2, N]]`

Note that there could be multiple solutions to this problem. We also want to compute the resulting list of indices of the permutation, so that we can apply the new ordering to any list associated with the original one.

Is there a name for this problem? Any efficient algorithms for it? Most of the solutions I can think of are very brute-force.

Comment: 1. count each element - O(N)
2. distribute them into two lists (5 As - L1, L2, L1, L2, L1, than 3 Bs - L2, L1, L2, etc) - O(N)
3. join lists - O(N)

Comment: 4. ah yes - indicies - O(N) again - just go through original list and fill indexing indicies.

Comment: 1.  Shuffle the list with the indices - O(N) 2.  Split the list in half O(1).  Sure, you wouldn't divide the symbols evenly every time, but on average...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a dictionary here, this will take `O(N)` time:

```
from  collections import defaultdict


lst = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', ' C', ' C', ' B', 'B']
d = defaultdict(list)
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    d[x].append(i)

items = []
indices = []
for k, v in d.items():
    n = len(v)//2
    items.extend([k]*n)
    indices.extend(v[:n])

for k, v in d.items():
    n = len(v)//2
    items.extend([k]*(len(v)-n))
    indices.extend(v[n:])

print items
print indices
```

**Output:**

```
['A', 'A', 'A', ' C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', ' C', 'B', 'B', ' B']
[0, 1, 4, 10, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 9, 13, 12]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by getting the rank order of the symbols, then picking alternate ranks for each half of the output array:

```
x = np.array(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A',
              'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B'])

order = np.argsort(x)
idx = np.r_[order[0::2], order[1::2]]

print(x[idx])
# ['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'C' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'C']
print(idx)
# [ 0  4  6  8  3 12 10  1  5  7  2  9 13 11]
```

By default [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) uses the quicksort algorithm, with average time complexity *O(N log N)*. The indexing step would be *O(1)*.

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle the list with the indices, then split it in half.  This method won't perfectly split the symbols every time, but as the number of repeats of each symbol gets larger, it will approach a perfect split.

```
import random

symbols = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B',  'C', 'C', 'B', 'B']
indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

both = zip(symbols, indices)
random.shuffle(both)

symbols2, indices2 = zip(*both)

print symbols2
print indices2
```

Some sample outputs:

Trial #1:

```
('A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C')
( 7,   10,  2,   4,   1,   13,  8,   0,   5,   6,   9,   3,   12,  11)
#                                  |
```

Trial #2

```
('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
( 6,   0,   9,   3,   11,  1,   8,   4,   13,  10,  7,   5,   2,   12)
#                                  |
```

Trial #3

```
('A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B')
( 4,   5,   11,  10,  2,   3,   0,   13,  12,  6,   7,   8,   1,   9)
#                                  |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` which is even better than just a `defaultdict` -- and you can place items into the first half and second half separately. That way, if you prefer, you can shuffle the first half and second half as much as you want (and just keep track of the shuffling permutation, with e.g. NumPy's `argsort`).

```
import collections

L = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B',  'C',  'C',  'B', 'B']

idx_L = list(enumerate(L))
ctr = collections.Counter(L)

fh = []
fh_idx = []
sh = []
sh_idx = []

for k, v in ctr.iteritems():
    idxs = [i for i,e in idx_L if e == k]
    fh = fh + [k for i in range(v//2)]
    fh_idx = fh_idx + idxs[:v//2]  
    sh = sh + [k for i in range(v // 2, v)] 
    sh_idx = sh_idx + idxs[v//2:]

shuffled = fh + sh
idx_to_shuffled = fh_idx + sh_idx
​
print shuffled
print idx_to_shuffled
```

which gives

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B']
[0, 1, 4, 10, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 9, 12, 13]
```

Comment: But the list comprehension to find the indices makes it `O(N)**2`, isn't it?

Comment: No, it would be `O(M*N)` where `M` is the number of distinct elements in the list (since the dict comprehension here is only over unique elements). If `M << N` then who cares. However, if `M ~ N` then you're way better off just shuffling the list since there are very few elements that need any special handling to ensure some copies of them are in the front half vs. back half (if you can abide some error, if you can't then yes some strictly O(N) approach is better).